# How to correctly handle question answered by another discussion, but not duplicate

Tags: discussion

In a comment, I pointed an OP to another discussion where the recommendation might help. The OP confirms that information solved the problem, but the Question was not a duplicate of that other discussion.

[Click on Start -> Microsoft word 2010 attaches a new blank document to existing instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349238/click-on-start-microsoft-word-2010-attaches-a-new-blank-document-to-existing?noredirect=1#comment56520554_34349238)

How should I correctly handle this? Do nothing? Copy the recommendation to the Answer and ask the OP to mark it? Mark it as a duplicate (doesn't feel right...)?

Answer (score 2):

I find both questions confusing but I do think they are duplicate.

The newer question seems clearer and better understandable due to the code. It can use an edit, maybe by using  some context from the older question.

You could try to nudge the OP in posting an answer with their code so we can clearly verify that the solution on both questions are similar. When the newer question is answered you can close vote the older one as a duplicate of the newer one.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying your suggestion...